# Android screen rotation not taking effect

Tags: android, kotlin, android-6.0-marshmallow, screen-orientation, screen-rotation

May I check how can I rotate screen via code in Android? 
The device (Android 6 ARM CPU) I am using does not have sensor to detect orientation change and I need to do it manually. 
The problem of this device is it will not save the setting, once I change the screen orientation via Setting menu. 
 The next time its power on, it will go back to default "Landscape".
I tried to use below codes (one at a time) to change it, it is not working (means screen no change).

```
Settings.System.putInt(contentResolver, Settings.System.USER_ROTATION, 1);

setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
```

On this device, there are two options (Screen rotation and External screen rotation). 
I need to change both orientation to achieve what I want via Settings - Display option. 
Either Kotlin or Java codes are Ok for me. Any advice?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't rotate android core from in you application, but you can create the custom layout in your project and controlled by your self like this :

**first create custom layout :**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class URotateLayout extends FrameLayout{
    public static final String TAG = "URotateLayout";
    public static final int ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
    public static final int ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
    public static final int ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE;
    public static final int ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT;
    public static final int ORIENTATION_SENSOR = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR;
    public static final int ORIENTATION_LOCKED = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED;

    private int mOrientation;
    private int mLastOrientation;

    private int mDefaultVideoContainerWidth;
    private int mDefaultVideoContainerHeight;

    private int mScreenWidth;
    private int mScreenHeight;

    public URotateLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public URotateLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public URotateLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public void updateScreenWidthAndHeight() {
        Display display = ((WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        display.getMetrics(metrics);
        mScreenWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
        mScreenHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
    }

    public boolean isLandscape() {
        updateScreenWidthAndHeight();
        return mScreenWidth > mScreenHeight;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        updateScreenWidthAndHeight();
        if (isLandscape()) {
            mDefaultVideoContainerWidth = mScreenWidth;
            mDefaultVideoContainerHeight = mScreenHeight;
        } else {
            mDefaultVideoContainerWidth = mScreenWidth;
         //   mDefaultVideoContainerHeight = mScreenWidth * 9 / 16;
            mDefaultVideoContainerHeight=mScreenHeight;
        }
        setMeasuredDimension(mDefaultVideoContainerWidth, mDefaultVideoContainerHeight);
    }

    public int getOrientation() {
        return mOrientation;
    }

    public void setOrientation(int orientation) {
        if (getContext() instanceof Activity) {
            Activity mActivity = (Activity) getContext();
            switch (orientation) {
                case ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
                    mActivity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                    break;
                case ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
                    mActivity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                    break;
                case ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE:
                    mActivity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
                    break;
                case ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT:
                    mActivity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
                    break;
                case ORIENTATION_SENSOR:
                    mActivity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
                    break;
                case ORIENTATION_LOCKED:
                    mActivity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED);
                    break;
            }
            mOrientation = orientation;
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    public void locked() {
        mLastOrientation = mOrientation;
        setOrientation(ORIENTATION_LOCKED);
    }

    public boolean isLocked() {
        return mOrientation == ORIENTATION_LOCKED ? true : false;
    }

    public void unlocked() {
        setOrientation(mLastOrientation);
    }

    public void toggleOrientation() {
        if (getContext() instanceof Activity && mOrientation != ORIENTATION_LOCKED) {
            Activity mActivity = (Activity) getContext();
            if (isLandscape()) {
                mActivity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
            } else {
                mActivity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
            }
            if (mOrientation == ORIENTATION_SENSOR) {
                getHandler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        setOrientation(mOrientation);
                    }
                }, 2000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Second add this to your layout, xml file like this :**

```
    <yourPackage_name.URotateLayout
        android:id="@+id/rotate_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

     <your_layout_here/>

    </yourPackage_name.URotateLayout>
```

**finally use it in your activity or fragment like this :**

```
   //define the view i use the **butterknife**
   @Bind(R.id.rotate_layout)
    URotateLayout rotateLayout;



    @Override
    public void toggleScreenOrientation() {
        if (rotateLayout != null) {
            rotateLayout.toggleOrientation();
        }
    }

    //use this for set oriention
    public void setScreenOriention(int oriention) {
            rotateLayout.setOrientation(oriention);
    }
```

Comment: This maybe helpful for others. I will leave it as it is. Reason for me cannot use this method is: User wants to rotate the whole screen (not only my app, the entire system screen). They do not want to go through details from Setting menu in order to change it.